# Moq verify uses objects modified in Returns, rather than what was actually passed in

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

**Background**

I have a class that uses NHibernate to persist objects to a database.  When you call `MergeEntity` for an object that does not have an ID set, NHibernate populates that object with an ID when it is returned.  In order to make sure I always use the same object as NHibernate is using, I pass that updated object back from my "`Save`" function.

**Problem**

I am trying to mock that same behavior using Moq, which is usually very intuitive and easy to use; however, I am having some trouble verifying that the calls to `Save()` are being made with the correct arguments.  I would like to verify that the ID of the object being passed in is zero, then that it is set properly by the `Save` function.  Unfortunately, when I modify the ID in the `Moq.Returns()` function, the `Moq.Verify` function uses the modified value rather than the value of the ID that was passed in.

To illustrate, here is a very basic class (I override the ToString() function so my test output will show me what ID was used when the mocked Save() is called):

```
public class Class1
{
    private readonly IPersistence _persistence;

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Object" /> class.</summary>
    public Class1(IPersistence persistence)
    {
        _persistence = persistence;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
       _persistence.Save(this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is the Interface (very straight forward):

```
public interface IPersistence
{
    Class1 Save(Class1 one);
}
```

And here is the test that I think should pass:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Save_NewObjects_IdsUpdated()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IPersistence>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<Class1>()))
            .Returns((Class1 c) =>
            {
                // If it is a new object, then update the ID
                if (c.Id == 0) c.Id = 1;

                return c;
            });

        // Verify that the IDs are updated for new objects when saved
        var one = new Class1(mock.Object);

        Assert.AreEqual(0, one.Id);

        one.Save();

        mock.Verify(x => x.Save(It.Is<Class1>(o => o.Id == 0)));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it fails saying that it was never called with arguments that match that criteria.  The only invocation to `Save` that was made on the mock is with an object that had an ID of 1.  I have verified that the objects have an ID of 0 when they enter the Returns function.  Is there no way for me to distinguish what was passed into the mock from what those objects are updated to be if I update the values in my `Returns()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch it up to verify that the Save was done with the correct object. And then assert that the Id was changed as expected.

```
[Test]
public void Save_NewObjects_IdsUpdated() {
    //Arrange
    var expectedOriginalId = 0;
    var expectedUpdatedId = 1;
    var mock = new Mock<IPersistence>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.Save(It.Is<Class1>(o => o.Id == expectedOriginalId)))
        .Returns((Class1 c) => {
            // If it is a new object, then update the ID
            if (c.Id == 0) c.Id = expectedUpdatedId;

            return c;
        }).Verifiable();

    var sut = new Class1(mock.Object);
    var actualOriginalId = sut.Id;

    //Act
    sut.Save();

    //Assert

    //verify id was 0 before calling method under test
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedOriginalId, actualOriginalId);
    //verify Save called with correct argument
    //ie: an object that matched the predicate in setup
    mock.Verify();
    // Verify that the IDs are updated for new objects when saved
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedUpdatedId, sut.Id);
}
```

By applying the filter on setup you and making it verifiable then you confirm that the method was actually called with an object that had an ID of zero.

I've tested this and it passes. To confirm that is works as expected you can change the id of sut from expected start id before doing act. Verify would fail as it does not match predicate.

This should satisfy what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That only tests the before and after state, which can be accomplished via many different means.  It does not test that the correct object was passed into the Save function.  As a matter of fact, I have other tests that do exactly as you have done here, but I had a bug where I was creating new objects all the time, rather than using existing ones, so I need a way to make sure I am passing the correct object in.

Comment: the `mock.Verify(x => x.Save(sut));` does check that the correct object was passed. You set it up with is any and then you confirm that the correct object, which in this case is the `Class1 sut` was passed into it

Comment: Sort of...except that when you are verifying it, 'sut' has the updated ID.  I want to test that the object that was passed in had an ID of zero.  This test does not verify that.

Comment: @MattZappitello then you need to change your setup and how you do your verification. Check the updated answer.

Comment: That looks like a reasonable workaround to this issue, but doesn't it seem like Moq should support what I was trying to do?  Why would it verify on the values that you updated versus what you passed in?

Comment: I don't know enough of the inner workings to say why it works this way and not the way you originally had it. I can only guess that it is comparing the current state of the object.

Comment: You could log an issue for it on GitHub if you believe that it should support what you were trying to do. Maybe the developers can provider better insight into the issue.

Comment: Yep.  I thought I would post here just in case I was completely off.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have indicated this as an answer, since I like this workaround a lot better than others; however, I still don't think it actually answers the question.  I have logged a bug with MOQ (https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/276), just in case anyone wants to go look at the discussion there.